# How to transpose a table in SQL? rows into columns. I have Wrong code

Tags: sql, sql-server, transpose

Hey I've got this table:

```
  WING         Presents            Waiting              CT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   A              30                  10                1
   B              40                  20                4
   C              26                  8                 2
   D              17                  14                3
```

I want to Transpose it to:

```
                    A           B         C           D
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Present            30          40         26          17
Waiting            10          20         8           14
CT                 1           4          2           3
```

I've tried this code from a question I saw here on StackOverflow:

```
  drop table if exists #b
  select R.*, row_number() over (order by R.WING) as seqnum
  into #b
  from #Res R  (my original table is #Res)


   select name,
   max(case when seqnum = 1 then val end),
   max(case when seqnum = 2 then val end),
   max(case when seqnum = 3 then val end),
   max(case when seqnum = 4 then val end)
   from #b cross apply
   (values (1, 'WING', 'WING'),
         (2, 'Presents', 'Presents'),
         (3, 'Waiting', 'Waiting'),
         (4, 'CT', 'CT'))
  v(ord, name, val)
  group by name, ord
  order by ord;
```

and it does not working... can someone help me??
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use the UNPIVOT and PIVOT functions. In this case you must know all of the values that you want to transform:

```
SELECT column_name, [A], [B], [C], [D]
  FROM (SELECT wing
             , column_name
             , value
          FROM <your_table>
       UNPIVOT (value for column_name in (Presents, Waiting, CT)) up) t
  PIVOT (MIN(value) FOR wing in ([A], [B], [C], [D])) p;
```

> UNPIVOT takes the list of columns and turns it into rows, the PIVOT then performs the final transformation into columns.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MlPbFqFd)